# How to map snake case yaml to camelcase java fields with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I have a yaml file with keys in camel case, like

```
---
start_date: "2018-09-01"
day_date: "2018-09-01"

userProduct:
    sales_channel: "1"
    user_group: "1"
```

And I have the following Java PoJos

```
public class Input{
    private String startDate = "";
    private String dayDate = "";

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Product userProduct;

   // getters/setters
}

public class Product {
   private salesChannel = "";
   private userGroup = "";

   // getters/setters
}
```

Now I want to read this with Jackson and I thought it would be sufficient to use

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
return objectMapper.readValue(inputData, Input.class); // inputData is the yaml as string
```

but this does not fill the nested objects. The `startDate` and `dayDate` from the `Input` object is correct, but `input.getUserProduct().getSalesChannel()` for example returns an empty string.

I also tried to use `user_product` instead of `userProduct` in the yaml file, but this does not change anything.

What is wrong here ? How can I define snake case in the yaml and camelcase in java ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem, which is to remove the nested objects. When having all fields inside the `Input` class and remove the `Product`, it works as expected.

I keep this question open nevertheless, as I'm still interested, whether this can be achieved with nested objects